# Kohana ORM: Get results based on value of a foreign table

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

```
taxonomies
 -id
 -name

taxonomy_type
 -taxonomy_id
 -type_id
```

I've configured two models:

```
class Model_Taxonomy{
protected $_has_many = array('types'=>array());
}

class Model_Taxonomy_Type{
protected $_belongs_to = array('taxonomy' => array());
}
```

*Please note that taxonomy_type is not a pivot table.*

A taxonomy can have multiple types associated.

Then, what I'm trying to do is get all taxonomies that belong to a given type id.
This is would be the SQL query I would execute:

```
SELECT * FROM taxonomies, taxonomy_type WHERE taxonomy_type.type_id='X' AND taxonomies.id=taxonomy_type.taxonomy_id
```

I've tried this:

```
$taxonomies = ORM::factory('taxonomy')
    ->where('type_id','=',$type_id)
    ->find_all();
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I can't find info about how execute this kind of queries so I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model_Taxonomy{
  protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'types' => array(
      'model' => 'Taxonomy_Type',
      'foreign_key' => 'taxonomy_id'
    )
  );
}

class Model_Taxonomy_Type{
  protected $_has_many = array(
    'taxonomies' => array(
      'model' => 'Taxonomy',
      'foreign_key' => 'taxonomy_id'
    )
  );
}
```

And use some like that:

```
$type = ORM::factory('taxonomy_type')
  ->where('type_id', '=', $type_id)
  ->find();

if( ! $type->taxonomies->loaded())
{
  types->taxonomies->find_all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`type_id` column is a PK of taxonomy_type table, am I right?
So, you have one (unique) `taxonomy_type` record, and only one related `taxonomy` object (because of `belongs_to` relationship). Instead of your:

> get all taxonomies that belong to a
>   given type id

it will be a

> get taxonomy for a given type id

Comment: Not exactly, PK of taxonomy_type table are both fields type_id and taxonomy_id. So I really want to get all taxonomies that has the type_id assigned. So, a taxonomy can have multiple types and a type can have multiple taxonomies associated.

Comment: consider type_id as a simple field